# How to generate control flow graph from Scala code?

Tags: eclipse, scala, compiler-construction, control-flow-graph

I want to see the control flow graph generated by the Scala compiler.  Is there a way to do so?  I tried searching online but only found Eclipse plugins for Java like the one from here www.drgarbage.com but none for Scala.

Thanks

EDIT: I took the .class file generated by scalac and opened that with the dr garbage plug in to see the bytecode visualized as a control flow graph.  But scalac makes 3 different .class files: Foo, Foo$, and Foo$delayedInit$body.  I see a bunch of disconnected graphs and only one of the graphs in Foo$ looks reasonable.  I tried searching online for the difference between the 3 .class files but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I believe `Foo` is your class, `Foo$` is the companion object, but I'm not sure about the last one.

Comment: Do you have a specific goal in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that the IR (intermediate representation) for scala in the backend was actually called icode.  The option in the compiler -Xprint-icode actually shows the IR separated into basic blocks.  This was what I was looking for.

Comment: This feature might be removed as of scala 2.12 - [see here](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M2). A better approach might be a compiler plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler plugin can do just that. However, it requires abstracting away some internals introduced by the compiler - which are more specific than what you'd expect from how a project's source code looks. You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/CANVE/extractor/tree/master/compiler-plugin) to get the raw information extracted for you, whereas the re-abstraction from the raw data is still work-in-progress, and you'd have to `sbt publishLocal` before you can include this plugin in your sbt definition.